# How to remove Frame Numbers Entirely in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am using `CambridgeUS` theme and I would like to remove frame numbers in the bottom right portion of the screen without actually destroying the theme.

Is that possible?

See in the below picture, the placeholder image will be my company logo and I want `1/1` next to it to disappear.

This is because there will be around 20 slides and as the numbers go from `1/20` through `10/20` that extra digit there causes my company logo to go a bit left, looks ugly in transition. I dont think I will be needing the frame numbers as this is only a 20 minute presentation.

Here is the code for below output:

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  %no navigation pane
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}


\title[Topic of the Presentation]{Topic of the Presentation}
\author[Person]{Person}
%\subtitle{}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\log_2o
\institute[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{placeholder.jpg}}
\date[{\includegraphics[height=2mm]{placeholder.jpg}}]{June 21st, 2018} 
%\subject{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\section{some section}
\subsection{some subsection}
\begin{frame}{\centerline{A Slide}}

Some Stuff

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: From the little logo in your footline I guess your using some custom footline definition. Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you set up your footline.

Comment: The too high placement of the text in your headline and name/title makes me think that you probably have an outdated beamer version.

Comment: My TexLiveUtility stopped working which is what I used for updating, but I guess you are right. There is 2018 Tex distribution available now, which I never installed. High placement of the text in headline and footline was annoying me, I hope that updating will be fixing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}` should do the trick.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame}
This is a frame
\end{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Another option is to set the frame numbering inside a fixed-width box that is `r`ight-aligned. For example, `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\makebox[5em][r]{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}`... Adjust `5em` accordingly.

Comment: This did not resolve my issue. But my Tex distribution is old, it could be that. I will try once it finishes updating.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This solves it but I need the 2018 distribution!