# How to remove page count from beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I have to remove the page count from Warsaw theme which is present there
[image: this is what I am talking about]\

Comment: It's hard to know for sure, since you didn't provide any code and we don't know for sure how the page numbers got there to begin with (—they aren't there in the Warsaw theme, but you're clearly using some other themes or options—) but have you tried `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}`?

Comment: Or maybe `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\insertpagenumber}` if you just want the current page number and not the count?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame}
This is a frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434782/how-to-remove-frame-numbers-entirely-in-beamer)